# Tying random seed to an instance of class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random, scipy

Suppose that I have a class TestClass(), that has methods that return random numbers generated by either random, numpy or scipy modules. How could I, without modifying the content of the TestClass() make, lets say two instances of the TestClass(), t1 and t2, that will always generate the same random numbers as each other?

For example, suppose that there is a method sample_from_normal_dist().

I would like to have the following behaviour.

```
print(t1.sample_from_normal_dist(), t2.sample_from_normal_dist())

print(t1.sample_from_normal_dist(), t2.sample_from_normal_dist())
```

Output:

0.75 0.75

-0.21 -0.21

And I want this to hold for all methods that have to do with generating random numbers.

Comment: Can you show us the code from TestClass() as its hard to say without knowing how your generating random numbers

Comment: "without modifying the content of the TestClass()" Why is this a constraint? If you can't modify the `TestClass`, how do you expect `TestClass` instances to be able to know which stream of random numbers to use, or to remember where they are in that stream? (Keep in mind that the outside code could ask for several random numbers from one instance before asking for any from another instance.)

Comment: An example could be:

def get_random():
      return random.random()

We can modify the class by for example adding a method set_seed(seed). But we are not allowed to change the content of the other methods.

That is okay. I primarily plan to call these one by one.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to use np.random.RandomState().

Create such an attribute and every time you sample you use that object to sample the random numbers.